# HTML input checkbox always returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this has been already asked. I checked all the previous question about this topic but I can't find a solution.

**This is the problem:** I have two input, one is a checkbox and the other one is a radio with three possible choices. Inside a function I have to see firstly if the first checkbox is checked, if yes I will check some other things with an if else statement, otherwise the function will proceed. The radio input will appear later inside the same function. This one will check which of the three choices had been checked previously and will set a variable equal to the value of the checked one. To see if the checkbox is checked I use jQuery with `.is(':checked')`, but it every returns `false`, even if I checked them. Any idea?

Sorry if I haven't properly used Stack Overflow, but this is my first question.

This is the HTML, the `input` is `#geoloc_waypoint_active` and the radio is `#locomotion_radio`

```html
<div id="create_route_modal_content" class="modal-body">
  <div id="geo_switch">
    <div id="geoSwitchDiv">
      <label for="geoloc_waypoint_active">
      Usa la tua posizione
      </label>
      <label class="switch">
        <input id="geoloc_waypoint_active" class="form-check form-check-inline" type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="locomotion_radio">
      <label><input class="locomInput" type="radio" name="locomotion" value="walking" checked><img class='locomotionImg' src='immagini/walking.png'></label>
      <label><input class="locomInput" type="radio" name="locomotion" value="cycling"><img class='locomotionImg' src='immagini/cycling.png'></label>
      <label><input class="locomInput" type="radio" name="locomotion" value="driving"><img class='locomotionImg' src='immagini/driving.png'></label>
    </div>
```

```js
DrawOnMap() {
  let formattedCoord = "";
  let geoposition = $('#geoloc_waypoint_active').is(':checked');
  console.log(geoposition)
  if (geoposition) {
    var geoL = $('#geo_Locator .mapboxgl-ctrl .mapboxgl-ctrl-icon');
    if (!map.getLayer('points') && geoL.attr('aria-pressed') === 'false') {
      alert("L'utente non ha una posizione attualmente attiva.");
      return;
    } else {
      this.waypoints.unshift(window.userPosition);
    }
  }

  if (this.waypoints.length < 2) {
    alert("Devi inserire almeno due punti di interesse.");
    return;
  }

  this.waypoints.forEach((waypoint, index, source) => {
    formattedCoord += waypoint[0] + "," + waypoint[1];
    if (index < source.length - 1) {
      formattedCoord += ";";
    }
  });

  let locomotion = $('input[name=locomotion]:checked').val();
```

`let geoposition = $('#geoloc_waypoint_active').is(':checked');` is always `false` and so It never enter the if

Same thing with `let locomotion = $('input[name=locomotion]:checked').val();` It can't find the checked one and set locomotion

Comment: when exactly do you call your DrawOnMap() function ? Because I just tried, and if you bind it let say to the onchange event of the checkbox, .is(':checked') returns the correct result

Comment: The only possible problem comes to my mind is you are calling the function before the checkbox being checked. You can try calling in $('#geoloc_waypoint_active').change(function() { DrawOnMap(); });

Comment: What does `console.log($('#geoloc_waypoint_active').length)` give you?

Comment: @freedomn-m It prints 1

Comment: My apologies, that will always be 1, try: `console.log($('[id=geoloc_waypoint_active]').length)` - if it's not 1, there's your issue.

Comment: `.is(":checked")` is the correct way to determine if a checkbox is checked.  There must be some other issue.  This might be that there is more than one control with the same ID and you're getting the wrong one  See https://jsfiddle.net/eb9w3z8g/1/ or you could be calling your code before it's ready.  To help you further, you'll need to update your question to include a **working snippet** that **demonstrates** the problem, see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this **$("#geoloc_waypoint_active")[0].checked** it will give you control right value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log($("#geoloc_waypoint_active")[0].checked)
 $('#check').on('click',function(){
    console.log($("#geoloc_waypoint_active")[0].checked)
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value='checkVakue' type='button' id='check'/>
<div id="create_route_modal_content" class="modal-body">
  <div id="geo_switch">
    <div id="geoSwitchDiv">
      <label for="geoloc_waypoint_active">
      Usa la tua posizione
      </label>
      <label class="switch">
        <input id="geoloc_waypoint_active" class="form-check form-check-inline" type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="locomotion_radio">
      <label><input class="locomInput" type="radio" name="locomotion" value="walking" checked><img class='locomotionImg' src='immagini/walking.png'></label>
      <label><input class="locomInput" type="radio" name="locomotion" value="cycling"><img class='locomotionImg' src='immagini/cycling.png'></label>
      <label><input class="locomInput" type="radio" name="locomotion" value="driving"><img class='locomotionImg' src='immagini/driving.png'></label>
    </div>
```